# Routing Error with Not Defined Model Property

Tags: node.js, express, routes, mongoose

I am running into a routing issue with Express 4, which is related to the properties I created for my mongoose schema. For some reason when I try a POST request, I am given a reference error that description is not defined. Did I mess up with my route request?

Error:

```
ReferenceError: description is not defined
at Object.handle (/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/travelApp/app/routes.js:47:5)
at next_layer (/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/travelApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:103:13)
at Route.dispatch (/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/travelApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:107:5)
at c (/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/travelApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:195:24)
at Function.proto.process_params (/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/travelApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:251:12)
at next (/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/travelApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:189:19)
at next_layer (/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/travelApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:77:14)
at next_layer (/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/travelApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:81:14)
at next_layer (/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/travelApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:81:14)
at Route.dispatch (/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/travelApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:107:5)
```

destination.js

```
 var mongoose   =   require('mongoose');
var Schema      =   mongoose.Schema;

var DestinationSchema   =   new Schema({
    tite:   String,
    description:    String,
    topOne:     String,
    topTwo:     String,
    topThree:   String,
    topFour:    String,
    topFive:    String
});

module.exports  =   mongoose.model('Destination', DestinationSchema);
```

routes.js:

```
module.exports = function(app, passport, Destination) {



    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.render('index.ejs')
    });

    app.get('/login', function(req, res) {

        res.render('login.ejs', {   message: req.flash('loginMessage')  });
    });

    app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
        successRedirect :   '/profile',
        failureRedirect :   '/login',
        failureFlash    :   true
    }));

    app.get('/signup', function(req, res) {
        res.render('signup.ejs', {  message: req.flash('signupMessage') });
    });

    app.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
        successRedirect :   '/profile',
        failureRedirect :   '/signup',
        failureFlash    :   true
    }));

    app.get('/profile', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
        res.render('profile.ejs', {
            user    : req.user
        });
    });

    app.get('/destinations', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
                res.render('destinations.ejs', {
                user    :   req.user
                });
            });

    app.post('/destinations', function(req, res) {

                var destination = new Destination();
                destination.name = req.body.name,
                destination.description = req.body.description,
                description.topOne = req.body.topOne,
                description.topTwo = req.body.topTwo,
                description.topThree = req.body.topThree,
                description.topFour = req.body.topFour,
                description.topFive = req.body.topFive;

                destination.save(function(err){
                    if (err)
                        res.send(err);

                    res.json({ message: 'Destination created.'});
                });

            });

    app.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
        req.logout();
        res.redirect('/');
    });





};




function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {

    if(req.isAuthenticated())
        return next();

    res.redirect('/');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
destination.name = req.body.name,
destination.description = req.body.description,
description.topOne = req.body.topOne,
description.topTwo = req.body.topTwo,
description.topThree = req.body.topThree,
description.topFour = req.body.topFour,
description.topFive = req.body.topFive;
```

Some are `destination` and some are `description`. I believe they all should be `destination` according your code above.

Comment: Yep. That corrected my problem. Never depend on autocorrect.